Rest API returns error HTTP/1.1 301
In the Rest Explorer, no matter what GET command I send, I get the same error response below. I've tried restarting my device, logging out and back in, logging in as an admin and non-admin. My other coworkers can login using the same credentials and can send GET commands just fine.
Just to be clear, I can login to my test org just fine with workbench. The is is only when I send a GET command that it gives me back this error.
Raw Response
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2024 21:51:10 GMT
Set-Cookie: CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; path=/; expires=Fri, 03-Oct-2025 21:51:10 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; secure
Set-Cookie: LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; path=/; expires=Fri, 03-Oct-2025 21:51:10 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; secure
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
X-Robots-Tag: none
Location: https://mobileinteractions2.test1.my.pc-rnd.salesforce.com/services/data/v62.0
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked



The first thing that jumps out to me is that /services/data/v62.0 is just the base url for a REST API call. You need to have a forward slash after v62.0 at the very least. In most cases, the path you input should be something like /services/data/v<version decimal here>/sobjects/<sObject here>/describe/
